# Openssl.Cnf impact on sshd services amazon linux

Tags: ssh, openssl, sshd, amazon-linux

I have Openssl V.1.0.1k-fips on my Amazon Linux machine and a few days ago I have added following parameter in my `openssl.cnf`

```
[ san_env ]

subjectAltName=${ENV::SAN}
```

and exported variable `export SAN=DNS:sitename`

and all went well.

Then after some time when I tried to log back in my server I am getting an error that `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. I know my keys are right because I used them last time when I was making changes and no network issue was there. I did nothing except that OpenSSL.cnf changes.

Now I did get my login back by commenting those lines in openssl.cnf (via long and hectic process) still, i don't get why this was happened, how does an OpenSSL.cnf impact on ssh service?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/465547/can-etc-ssl-openssl-cnf-impact-sshd Though not answering why it is so. The server logs would be helpful.

Comment: Your issue seems like this one: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/43902 Are you using RedHat? It may be there own specific OpenSSH server has been modified to be using openssl in some way. What does `ldd /usr/sbin/sshd` say? Does it link to openssl libraries in any way?